# How to order column names of r dataframe with respect to other dataframe column order

Tags: r

I have a R dataframe with column orders as follows

```
      Name,ID,Class,Division
```

I have another dataframe with same columns but,with different order.

```
     ID,Class,Division,Name
```

I want above dataframe column orders to be same as that of the first one. How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: In my opinion, it's better just to `rbind` the two tables and avoid worrying about incongruent column orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can order the second dataframe columns using the column names of the first (assuming both of them have the same column names)

```
df2[names(df1)]
```

---

If it is a `data.table`, use `setcolorder`

```
library(data.table)
setcolorder(df2, names(df1))
```